# How to create a simple line break in a label using Google Apps Script (GAS)?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I am completely new to coding so this maybe a noob question but is there a simple way to create a line break in Google Apps Script that will print to the screen? For example if I have a label like this:

```
  I want to create a 
      line break
or blank line of space

   wherever I wish, 

without using multiple 
 labels or textboxes.
```

Would this even be possible? I have seen an example where they suggest using "\n" but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code.

```
function doGet() {
       var app = UiApp.createApplication();
       app.add(app.createHTML("<br/>I want to create a 
      <br/>line break
      <br/>or blank line of space
      <br/>  wherever I wish, 
      <br/>  without using multiple 
      <br/> labels or textboxes."));
       return app;
     }
```